# Find $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n - a^n}{x - a}$ for some parameter $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem is stated as:

"Find  $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n - a^n}{x - a}$ for some parameter $a \in \mathbb{R}$. (Hint: Do you recognize this limit? If not, you can always simplify the fraction using long division.)"

But to be honest, I really don't know how to tackle this problem and the hint doesn't ring a bell. Normally I would try to make an attempt similar to the following example:

$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x^3 + 2x^2 + 2}{3x^3 + x + 4} \approx \lim_{x \to - \infty} \frac{x^3}{3x^3} = \frac{1}{3}$

Looking at the degree of the numerator and the denominator, comparing them and cutting off the uninteresting parts, but that approach doesn't seem to fit here.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

I tried to rewrite the given answer in a different way which is more accessible to my way of thinking:

\begin{align}
\frac{x^n - a^n}{x - a} &= (x-a) \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}x^{n-k}\\
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n - a^n}{x - a} &= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{(x-a) \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}x^{n-k}}{x - a}\\ 
&= \lim_{x \to a} \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}x^{n-k}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}a^{n-k}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1+n-k}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{n-1}\\
&= na^{n-1}
\end{align}

Comment: What is the derivative of $f(x)=x^n$ at $x=a$ by definition?

Comment: why donot you use L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule is way overkill here, and could be viewed as being a little circular, since this is the limit that comes up in the definition of the derivative of the numerator...

Comment: it will be easier to factor the numerator if you change the variable from $x$ to $h$ by $x = a+h.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another way:**

The expression $x^n-a^n$ can be factor as $$x^n-a^n=(x-a)\left(x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+a^2x^{n-3}+\ldots+a^{n-1}\right)$$

Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}&=\lim_{x\to a}\left(x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+a^2x^{n-3}+\ldots+a^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\underbrace{a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}+\ldots+a^{n-1}}_{n\text{ times}}\\
&=\color{red}{na^{n-1}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot! I tried to write your explanation a bit different, so it sticks better in my head. See update above.